# C++. Циклы и удаление элементов из вектора

Tags: c++, vector

Возникла проблема. Есть вектор чисел `arr`, к примеру 
{1, -1, -1, 2, -2, 1, 1}.
Нужно написать функцию которая примет этот вектор и удалит противоположные по знаку элементы если они стоят рядом. Написал вот такой код, но ничего не выходит. Должно вернуть 1, а возвращает -2, почему? Может кто знает решение лучше? 
`arr` - начальный вектор
`result_vec` - результирующий вектор, в начале равен arr

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

std::vector<int> someFunc(std::vector<int>& arr);

int main() {

std::vector<int> d1 = { 1, -1, -1, 2, -2, 1, 1 };
std::vector<int> ans1 = someFunc(d1);

for (int x : ans1) {
    std::cout << x << " "; // вывод результата
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}

std::vector<int> someFunc(std::vector<int>& arr)
{

std::vector<int> result = arr;
// проход по элементам массива
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < result.size() - 1; j++) { // здесь использую проход по result, т.к. каждый раз его размер уменьшается 
        if ((arr[j] == -1 * arr[j + 1])) {
            result.erase(result.begin() + j);
            result.erase(result.begin() + j);
        }
    }
}
return result;

}
```

Comment: Согласно вашему описанию в векторе должны остаться следующие элементы { -1, 1, 1 }, так как  в данной под-последовательности  { -1, 2, -2, 1 }  -1 и 1 не являются смежными элементами. Они разделены элементами { 2, -2 }

Comment: итерации должны происходить пока в векторе не останется противоположных чисел стоящих рядом. в Вашем варианте проведя еще одну итерацию получим {1}.

Comment: Тогда имеет место неоднозначность решения. Рассмотрите последовательность пар { { 1, 'A' }, { 2, 'B' }, { -2, 'C'  }, { -1, 'D' }, { 1, 'E' } }, где рассматриваются противоположность знаков первых элементов пар.  Тогда в результате в зависимости от реализации вы можете получить последовательность, состоящую из элемента либо { { 1, 'A' } } либо { { 1, 'E' } }

Comment: Еще один вопрос возникает - это что делать с рядом стоящими нулями? Они удаляются, или не считается, что они имеют противоположные знаки?

Comment: нулей нету среди чисел нету. (условие)
а Ваше прошлое сообщение я, если честно, не понял.

Comment: Данная конструкция  result_vec.erase(arr.begin() + j);  не имеет смысла. Вы для вектора result_vec используете итератор мектора arr.

Comment: исправил.
неверно скопировал сюда. 
код всё равно не рабочий.

Comment: Так не понятно, что такое arr и что такое result_vec, и какие они имеют значения.  Представьте минимальный компилируемый пример, воспроизводящий проблему.

Comment: Готово. Код вписал.

Comment: Используйте в циклах только обращение к вектору result. Почему там вообще существуют ссылки на вектор arr?!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55783/discussion-between---and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: Я не принимаю участие в чатах.

Comment: Хорошего вечера :)
Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 1):

Не самый эффективный вариант, но тем не менее

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
  std::vector<int> a = { 1, -1, -1, 2, -2, 1, 1 };

  auto p = [](int a, int b) { return a == -b; };

  std::vector<int>::iterator it;
  while ((it = std::adjacent_find(a.begin(), a.end(), p)) != a.end()) 
    do
    {
      it = a.erase(it, it + 2);
      it = std::adjacent_find(it, a.end(), p);
    } while (it != a.end());

  std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```